# Process.Start(); as another user works but explorer.exe iexplore.exe throws exception

Tags: c#, exception, process.start

I'm having problems with a program and its buttons (I know, I'm awesome lol) the buttons can be "programmed" to run programs. They also can be set to run as admin (different credentials).
If I set up simply notepad or cmd or explorer it runs like charm. But if I start iexplore it has got no admin rights.
I had problems before with running explorer.exe the solution was that I had to run it by typing the full path C:\windows\explorer.exe to be able to run it but that I solved it by setting up the VB2015 compiler (?) to Platform target: x64.
My other problem is that if I try to run dsa.msc or generally anything ends with msc it throws the following exception, even if I set up the full path to the syswow64 (or the system32) folder like c:\windows\syswow64\dsa.msc
"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

Running the C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe "services.msc" (or syswow64, with or without the /computer= switch) throws 
"The requested operation requires elevation." which I have since I'm able to run services.msc (and all other msc-s from command line with the same user rights)
Thank you.
A beginner.

Comment: The `"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform." ` message is valid because you can only start executables, like exe, msi or bat. The `"The requested operation requires elevation."` means you need to run the program as administrator. You might try to start your host process as administrator, as a test to see if it works.

Comment: Running the host app as admin wasn't the idea, but that will be the case since I do need to run tasks such as get the logged in user on a remote pc as admin anyway and telling the app to run those few in normal user mode is much easier indeed. Running iexplore still opens the IE with normal user rights which is weird. (giving the ufll path does the trick tho)
Is there a way to run the .msc-s? I'll try something (write a void if the app-to-be-opened ends with msc, run it in the mmc.exe-way.)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't need to run the host app as administrator! There is a variable (inside your [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) instance) called `StartInfo` (which is an instance of the [ProcessStartInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)), where [Verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb(v=vs.110).aspx) could be used as followed:

```
Process p = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("E:\\Users\\Temp\\app.exe")
    {
        Verb = "runas"
    }
};

p.Start();
```

This will prompt the user to run the `app.exe` as administrator.

---

### Edit

Running a [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) as a defined user:

```
Process p = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("E:\\Users\\Temp\\app.exe")
    {
        Verb = "runas",
        Arguments = "/user:Vira"
    }
};
```

For more information about those `RUNAS Arguments`, click [me](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx)! :)

Comment: I was trying to say with "as admin (different credentials)" that it's not THE administrator account I'm using to run the app but AN account with elevated/some admin rights. Sorry my bad.

Comment: I am thankful for your help and I don't want to be a troll, but then what is [Process.Start Method (String, String, String, SecureString, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t(v=vs.110).aspx) for?

Comment: @Nash It's pretty much the same. The documentation is calling it an `alternative to the explicit steps of creating a new Process `. I won't suggest it, because you won't have so much control over the parameters of the process.

Comment: My problem is that it's not possible to pass the previously stored password to the runas. (afaik)

Comment: @Nash Think about how silly it would be if microsoft inplemented a method accepting a password... it would require developers to store passwords inside code! Please **DON'T** save passwords inside your source code! The `RUNAS` command will prompt the user to enter his credentials, so don't worry.

Comment: @Nash maybe I've misunderstood you. Then I'd suggest adding the `/savecred` argument too. I've provided you with a link containing the documentation of `RUNAS` argumemts...

Comment: I must be the dumbest person on this planet but this:
`Process p = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd")
                {
                    Verb = "runas",
                    UseShellExecute = true, //with or without
                    Arguments = " /user:DOMAIN\\username"
                }
            };
            p.Start();`
opens for me a cmd where I type whoami and my own username is showing up not the users in the /user: line.
(i also can't use the  formatting...:))

Comment: The [Whoami](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299(v=ws.11).aspx) command is meant to get the currently logged in user! Try using `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FI "USERNAME eq Vira"`instead. (Replace `Vira`)

Comment: INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria. (with my own username however i can see the opened cmd.exe in the list)
never mind, thank you for your help. I'll find another way.